# Automatically connect lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am building a path with a loop (or few loops actually) and using `line width=1mm`, so the lines are quite visible on the drawing. What strikes the observer is that the lines are not connected in the human sense, but touches each other at one point.

[image: the image of the problem]

It is an unsatisfactory result. Is there an automatic way to connect lines in a way, that path does. like,

[image: the expected connection image]

The MWE,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width = 1mm] (0, 0) -- ++ (1,0);
        \draw[line width = 1mm] (0, 0) -- ++ (0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The actual code, that draws a snake-like path on the grid

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iN}{6}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iM}{7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\slightoffset}{0.2} %cm

        \begin{scope}[opacity=0.2]
            \draw (0, 0) grid (\iM, \iN);
            \draw[line width=0.3mm] (0, 0) rectangle (\iM, \iN);
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.5, -0.5)},transparency group,overlay, line width = 1mm]%, line cap=rect] - the solution
        
                \draw (\iM+\slightoffset, \iN) -- ++(0, -\iN + 1);
                \foreach \row in {1, ..., \iN}
                {
                    \draw (1, \row) -- (\iM - \slightoffset, \row);
                }
                \begin{scope}
                    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (\iM + \slightoffset, \iN);
                    
                    \foreach \row in {1, 3, ..., \iN}
                    {
                        \draw (1, \row) -- ++(0, 1);
                    }
                    \foreach \row in {2, 4, ..., \iN}
                    {
                        \draw (\iM - \slightoffset, \row) -- ++(0, 1);
                    }
                \end{scope}
            
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the `line cap=rect` or the `line cap=round` options (default value is `butt`). See TikZ/pgf manual, p.175.

Comment: you need to show your source if you want people to tell you what to change, but from the image I would guess you have drawn two separate paths instead of one path

Comment: Even with loops, one can make a continuous path from different ones. But we can't help you until we see what you did. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @PaulGaborit, this indeed solved the problem.

Comment: @SebGlav, added an example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this is intended. Maybe I'm missing the point of how to build a path, while not drawing it continuously?

Comment: you can (usually) arrange to collect the path segments in your loop and then draw one combined path rather than draw each segment as it comes, but it depends on the details you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, added the code, though it could be another question.

Comment: In this case, I think that you didn't manage well your path automation. Is `line cap = rect` enough for you or do you want something else? There's no *in house* way to do what you ask (a single path from multiple separated ones) but you can do it if you change your way of construction. It depends on what you want to achieve as a path.

Comment: I am satisfied with the `line cap` solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438850/14500